# Какой способ написания кода используется в реальной работе Python

Tags: python, code-style

Я учу Python, прохожу курс на Udemy, преподаватель показывает все примеры используя
List Comprehension,а мне понятнее и удобнее использовать методы типа find и тд. Какой из способов чаще используется в реальных проектах? Вот пример задания:

*Создайте функцию is_cat_here(), которая принимает любое количество аргументов и проверяет есть ли строка 'cat' среди них. Функция должна возвращать True, если такой параметр есть и False в обратном случае. Буквы в строке 'cat' могут быть как большие, так и маленькие*

Вариант решения преподавателя:

```
def is_cat_here(*args):
    args_in_lower_case = [str(argument).lower() for argument in list(args)]
    if 'cat' in args_in_lower_case:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Мой вариант решения:

```
def is_cat_here(*args):
    my_pet = input().lower()
    for i in args:
        if i.lower().find(my_pet) != -1:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Comment: Не скажу о реальных проектах, сам учу пока, но на мой взгляд ответ преподавателя более "питонообразно" выглядит. Можете ещё на скорость запустить, если интересно, и увидеть, что быстрее работает.

Comment: Всю функцию можно записать в одну строку: `is_cat_here = lambda *args: 'cat' in [str(x).lower() for x in args]`

Comment: А ваш вариант решения просто неверный, потому что он вернёт False сразу же, как не найдёт my_pet в первом элементе списка args

Comment: А ещё ваш вариант с find неверен потому, что какое-нибудь `'catfish'.find('cat') != -1` тоже вернёт True

Comment: Ваш короче, значит лучше. Только исправьте его

Comment: "Короче - лучше" - это спорно в общем случае. Можно написать коротко, но запутано. Я за "проще и понятней - лучше, даже если длинней". Конкретно в этом случае мне нравится вариант без лямбды с функцией из одной строки `return any ('cat' == str(x).lower() for x in args)`

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA, но тут встает вопрос -- для кого понятней? / В этом разрезе уж добавьте перд своим return ... `def is_cat(*args) : ` (можно в той же строке)

Comment: Это хороший вопрос. Думаю, что целевой аудиторией должен быть разработчик того уровня, который мы хотим видеть в проекте. Это значит, что мы не подстариваемся под джунов, лучше чтоб они подтягивались до уровня, но и слишком усложнять код без надобности - плохо (уж если есть веская причина, то комментируем соответственно). Ну и уж точно должен быть хотя бы один другой разработчик, который может качественно проревьюировать код. Повторюсь, что основной мой тезис, что краткость кода - это в общем случае плохая метрика, но я согдасен - во многих случаях более короткий код более понятен и прост.

Comment: В задаче сказано, что нужно искать cat, а ваш вариант зачем-то запрашивает строку для поиска у пользователя.